# Ajax and Rails 4: Create instance variable and update view without refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial of the index of coaching_notes with a form for creating notes. I want to create a coaching note and have the partial update without a page refresh. I get an Unknown Action error: The action 'show' could not be found for CoachingNotesController. If I add the show action, I get a missing template error. I've also gotten Unknown format errors when I try removing the format.html parts from controller.

I modeled my code after Rails docs and also reviewed a bunch of similar situations but can't get it to work.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

**/views/coaching_notes/_index.html.erb**

```
<div id="coaching_notes">
  <% @coaching_notes.each do |note| %>
    <li> <%= note.content %> </li>
  <% end %>
</div>
<br>
<% @coaching_note = CoachingNote.new(user_id: current_user.id, meeting_id: session[:current_meeting_id]) %>
<%= form_for(@coaching_note, remote: true) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :meeting_id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :archive %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**/views/coaching_notes/_coaching_note.html.erb**

```
<li><%= note.content %></li>
```

**/views/coaching_notes/create.js.erb**

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render coaching_note) %>").appendTo("#coaching_notes");
```

**/controllers/coaching_notes_controller.rb**

```
def create
@coaching_note = CoachingNote.new(coaching_note_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @coaching_note.save
    format.html { redirect_to @coaching_note, notice: 'note was successfully created.' }
    format.js   {}
    format.json { render json: @coaching_note, status: :created, location: @coaching_note }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @coaching_note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :coaching_notes
```

**UPDATE 7/15/17**
 - I've modified a couple files according to @Cira's answer:

**/views/coaching_notes/_index.html.erb**

```
<div id="coaching_notes">
  <% @coaching_notes.each do |note| %>
    <li> <%= note.content %> </li>
    <%= link_to "delete", note, :remote => true, :method => :delete, :data => {:confirm => "Are you sure?"} %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<br>
<% @coaching_note = CoachingNote.new(user_id: current_user.id, meeting_id: session[:current_meeting_id]) %>
<%= form_for(@coaching_note, remote: true) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, id: 'user' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :meeting_id, id: 'meet' %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :archive, id: 'arch' %>
  <%= f.text_field :content, id: 'content' %>

  <%= f.submit 'Add note', id: 'submit_note' %>
<% end %>

// newly added
<script>
$('#submit_note').on( "click", function() {
  var u = $('#user').val()
  var m = $('#meet').val()
  var a = $('#arch').val()
  var c = $('#content').val()

  $.ajax({
    url: "/coaching_notes/create",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      user_id: u,
      meeting_id: m,
      archive: a,
      content: c
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(info) {
      $('#coaching_notes').data( "html", info )
    }
  });
})
</script>
```

(*the main part that I don't know about is the success function with the data attribute*)

**/controllers/coaching_notes_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @coaching_note = CoachingNote.new(coaching_note_params)

    @html = render_to_string :partial => "coaching_notes/index"
    respond_to do |format|
      if @coaching_note.save
        format.html
        format.json { render json: {"html" => @html} }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @coaching_note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Two things:
1. Does my success function look right in the ajax?
2. Do I need to put `if @coaching_note.save` in the controller?

The error I'm now getting is 'NoMethodError in CoachingNotes#create - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass' highlighting this line in coaching_notes/index.html

```
<% @coaching_notes.each do |note| %>
```

Then I get 'Missing template coaching_notes/index'

I feel like we're getting close! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It turns out the problem was that I was MISSING THIS LINE in my application.js:**

```
 //= require jquery_ujs
```

For those who don't know, ujs stands for 'Unobtrusive JavaScript'. Without requiring this, `remote: true` will not be much help.

Before figuring this out, I did find a solution using just javascript and ajax, here's the script for deleting notes:

```
$("input[value='Del']").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var num = this.id
    $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "/coaching_notes/" + this.id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          // remove the div containing the note
        }
    });
});
```

Note that you need to use `preventDefault()` to prevent the form from submitting.

And the script for adding note definitely could be refactored more but works nonetheless:

```
$(document.body).delegate('input:text', 'keypress', function(e) {
    // if user hits enter key
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
      createNote()
    }
})

$("#submit_note").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  createNote()
})

function createNote() {
  var u = $('#user').val()
  var m = $('#meet').val()
  var a = $('#arch').val()
  var c = $('#content').val()

  if (c != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/coaching_notes",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "coaching_note": {
          "user_id": u,
          "meeting_id": m,
          "archive": a,
          "content": c
        }
      },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(note) {
        $("#content").val('') // clears the input box
        // add the new note here
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The part about delegating keypresses is so the notes get sent when user hits the 'enter' key. Again, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the form from being submitted via Rails.

Hope this helps others! I know I was stuck on it for a while and it was a super easy fix. Don't forget! **MAKE SURE YOU HAVE THIS IN YOUR APPLICATION.JS!**

```
 //= require jquery_ujs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I think what you can do is possibly pass the form's data into a controller action (create) via AJAX when the user presses the submit button

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/coaching_notes/create",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {a hash of the data retrieved from the inputs},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        //replace data of div you want here using String(data["html"], html being the attribute passed back via json from the controller.
                    }
                });
```

and in your controller render the partial again after creating your coaching note like this:

```
@html = render_to_string :partial => "coaching_notes/index"
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render json: {"html" => @html}}
      end
```

and send the HTML back into the view using AJAX and replace the HTML of the original div of coaching notes under the ajax success function.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks @Cira, I still don't have it working yet but I updated my changes for you to take a look at. I'm very grateful for any help!

Comment: The success attribute in AJAX means that only when the AJAX call is successful does it perform the success function, I think data is the parameter that you have to put instead of info. Also for your coaching_notes, there should be no s I think, since your variable name is coaching_note. I'm also not quite sure why your index is a partial, maybe create another file as the partial and make the index not a partial?